# Search by custom field with searchkit

Tags: searchkit

Is it possible to search contacts by custom fields with SearchKit ? I can't find a way to do it.

I need to list contacts where

```
Contact Subtype = "parent" and "has a relationship with a child" => this is working
    OR
Contact Subtype = "parent" and "Custom field::School name=XXX" => I can't find how to do this
```

(In the result table, I can successfully add the custom fields, but I can't use them in the query)

Any thoughts ?

Comment: Certainly doable using the 'Where' function I would have thought, is the school name field set to be searchable in the settings?

Comment: Using "where" is what I had in mind, but no custom field appears anywhere (or well hidden in submenus and didn't find them)
Yes the field is searchable, I use it successfully in the "traditionnal" search methods in Civi

Comment: The menus can take getting used to. It's still hard to pinpoint as there's a number of combinations as to why it may not be there (i.e. the entity the custom field is related to) etc. If you replicate your field settings on dmaster or provide some more detail here, I'm sure one of use in the community can help.

Comment: I've just seen a system alert saying I had to update the database structure because of a new extension. Probably after Search kit installation. After doing so, I can now see the custom fields. Not 100% sure this was the root cause, but it seems so :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Worth checking to see if your db might need an update running as some extension or core upgrade can require the db to have the upgrade run also.

Comment: Thx @petednz, this is exactly what I found in the meantime, and since the db update, problem solved :)